Output format camera OV5642
I cannot figure out the output data format YUV 4:2:0 for the OV5642 camera.
The documentation states that one of the possible output sequences is YYYY.../ YUVV....
However, I don’t understand how this sequence will be output on the camera pins D[7:0].
For example, the documentation for the OV7670 camera provides an illustration showing how the RGB444 format is output on D[7:0].

From it, it’s clear that the 4 most significant bits in the first byte are garbage, followed by 4 bits of R, 4 bits of G, and 4 bits of B.
Will this be the case for YUV 4:2:0 as well?
Or will the YYYY.../ YUVV... sequence result in a two-byte sequence [YYYY YUYV] [YUYV YYYY], where the last 4 Y values already belong to the next pixel?
A similar question was already asked at this "What does yuv420 output mean in camera?" . But I couldn’t find an answer there or I didn’t understand it.
Thank you in advance.
